# Fragment Transition not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

In my app I have 3 tabs(buttons) and on its swipe I am changing the fragment.So for this I am using slide left and slide right animations.But it seems not working for me.

Slide_Left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueFrom="2000"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</set>
```

Fragment Call

```
try {
    String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
    String fragmentTag = backStateName;


    FragmentManager manager = activity.getFragmentManager();
    boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);
    if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) == null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(id, fragment, fragmentTag);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in, R.animator.slide_out);
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        ft.commit();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `((Activity) getActivity()).overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_in,R.animator.slide_out);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **SlidingTabLayout** with **ViewPager** instead of this manual animation...
Refer following link ...
Its easy
https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html

```
private class SlideAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public SlideAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return your_first_fragment_object;
                case 1:
                    return your_first_fragment_object;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Your First tab";
                case 1:
                    return "Your Second tab";
            }
            return super.getPageTitle(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2; // No of tab you want
        }

    }
```

Thats it...
Now Just assign this adapter to ViewPager using setAdapter()
...

Comment: Yes i know but i wanted the customized tabs and i dont know how to customize it

Comment: Sir this things i Know,but query is that the tabs i want is different not the normal ones

Comment: can you give me sample layout of your tabs ...?

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=764253FA95B1B6F8!2174&authkey=!AJ8K50p-L-UTAg4&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: Thats the link for what i want

Comment: Are you talking about today | tommorow | Later tab in layout or swipe left/right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78861/discussion-between-anuj-and-moinkhan).

Answer (score 0):

It may help

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:

            frag = UsageRecoSummaryFragemrent.newInstance(position);
            // changeColor(newColor);

            break;
        case 1:
            frag = SmsDetailsFrag.newInstance(position);

            break;
        case 2:
            frag = CallDetailsFragment.newInstance(position);

            break;
        case 3:
            frag = MobileDataUsageFragment.newInstance(position);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        fragmentReferences.put(position, new WeakReference<Fragment>(frag));
        return frag;
}
```